# Comprehensive way to indicate error code using single LED

Tags: led, fpga

I am implementing Altera remote update mechanism, and it does not work, configuration falls back to the factory one.

I need to get the cause of it, and the only output I have is single LED.
Remote update state machine outputs 5 bits ([page 35](https://www.altera.com/content/dam/altera-www/global/en_US/pdfs/literature/ug/ug_altremote.pdf), `111` in the table).

My thoughts:

- Blinking number of times binary represents is bad idea :), thus LED should somehow display bit states;
- Circuit is having input clock, thus I can time the blinking for easy value readout;
- Separating start, 1s, 0s and end: display "message" in loop, starting with 1 second long turn on (start), then one short blink for 0 or two short blinks for 1 within the second, then pause of a second, then display next bit, and at the end of 5-bit sequence the start goes again (1 second long turn on).

Is there any better way, or even standard and proven way in *semaphore signalling*, to achieve value readout effectively by the human?

P.S. I do not know which tags for my question are the right ones! Please edit if needed.

Comment: Why dont you just flash yourself a couple of times to indicate the start of a code, then flash the value in binary. There are a multitude of other encodings you could try, as well.

Comment: i would write a sequence/protocol that can be shone into a phone's camera and decoded into a human-friendly message using an app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you really have is one LED, the best way of doing this (from an end-user perspective) will probably be to use a set of counted blinks.

Consider the following scheme, for example:

- Break the 5-bit code into groups of 2, 2, and 1 bits. (3 bits would lead to a group of up to 8 flashes, which is too close to the limit of what a user can reliably count.)
- Add 1 to the value of each group, resulting in numbers from 1-4, 1-4, and 1-2 in each respective group. (This is important -- having any of the groups display as zero will make the resulting sequence difficult or even impossible to read!)
- Repeat the following sequence:

  1. Blink the LED on and off at 200 ms intervals to count off the first group.
  2. Wait for 500 ms -- just a little bit longer than it'd take to blink one more time, to make it clear that this is a gap.
  3. Blink at 200 ms intervals again for the second group.
  4. Wait for 500 ms again.
  5. Blink at 200 ms intervals again for the third group.
  6. Wait for 2000 ms before starting the loop again, to make a long, clear gap between each time the code appears.

Here's an example of what this would look like for 4/2/2 blinks (binary 11/01/1). Users should be able to describe this pretty reliably as "four flashes, then two flashes, then two more flashes".

[image]

Comment: I consider all answers as very good ones, but this one is the easiest to implement in FPGA, has clear example and even visualization. I implemented it; the only change I did is slowed down flashing speed twice - as sometimes I was unable to count flashes (was it two or three?).

Answer (score 6):

I have used a lock-in amplifier which would blink out its IP address using a single LED. It would flash 1-10 times to encode each decimal digit, with gaps between digits and longer gaps for the groups.  It didn't work very well, watching and writing it down was quite error prone.  Fortunately you have 5 bits not 32 bits, so it should be easier. Suggestions:

- You are trying to communicate 5 bits, not a 5-bit number, so sending it in binary (as you have suggested) is a good idea.  If you were sending a number from 0 to 32, with 32 different meanings, you could consider decimal or octal or similar.
- Representing bits with long and short flashes might be easier than one/two flashes.
- Five bits is not too many, so it should be possible for the user to remember all of them, without stopping half way to write them down. This means they can go faster than you've suggested.

My initial solution would be to have five flashes, at half second intervals, then a one to two second wait, then repeat.  This means that a 0 would be represented by 100ms on, 400ms off, and a 1 would be represented by 400ms on, 100ms off. If I was then using such an interface as a customer, I'd probably watch the light for a few repeats whilst muttering to myself "long, long, short long, short", until I was sure I had the right pattern, then write it down and look it up.

Answer (score 2):

A far better approach for signalling error conditions on a single LED is to using a concept of a series of long pulses followed by a series of short pulses. The pulse sequence is followed by a longer off time and then repeating the sequence of long and short pulses until the user comprehends the code being reported and resets the unit.

In my implementations, either in MCU software or in FPGA logic, I have found the following pulse timing parameters to be optimal.

LONG PULSE ON TIME = **700 msec**

SPACE BETWEEN LONG PULSES = **500 msec**

DELAY FROM LONG TO SHORT PULSES = 200 msec (after last long pulse space)

SHORT PULSE ON TIME = **100 msec**

SPACE BETWEEN SHORT PULSES = **500 msec**

DWELL TIME TO REPEAT = **1900 msec** (after last short pulse space)

User instructions should indicate that long pulse counting comes before short pulses.

Experience with this system shown that the optimum number of long or short pulses should not exceed five pulses for the most common error conditions. That gives a total of 25 possible common error reports. The most likely error conditions should be assigned to combinations with the lowest number of pulses.

I often group the error reports into classes based upon the number of long pulses and the short pulse count is the error within the class.

Error codes are nicely documented as 11, 12, 13....21, 22....31, 32, 33 etc.

I have never found a reason in any given product to have more than about 15 error codes. In rare instances where more than 25 are needed you can resort up to 6 long and short pulses to get up to 36 codes.

Comment: Coding the full alphabet is possible using short and long pulses. The concept is known for decades as the Morse alphabet. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code  
Of course digits are also coded. So why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @Uwe, Way to complicated for ordinary users that simply want to have a handful of error codes displayed. So there is a completely different type of wheel here as opposed to spelling out complete words.

Comment: @Uwe - About five years ago I made a gadget that would pulse out a Morse code message string from a selection of some 400 well known quotes and expressions once per hour as a game with a champion ham radio operator to see if he was able to visually decode Morse code as opposed to the audible decoding he normally heard off his radio rig. This "game" went on for about two years and in the end he was able to figure out many of the quotes but he said it was very difficult to decode visually.